# how do i create layout like this

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

```css
.main
{      
  height: 500px;
}
.top
{
  background-image:url("banner_bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class = "top main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

hey guys i have one question how to create layout like i have provided in the comment box. also i have provided my code link what i have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: layout i'm trying to create like this but dont know how to create it please help me out i'm new in css ibb.co/b1G0Fa

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the image has the same dimensions of the div, I think this is the most elegant solution:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/4f9ojsvb/1/)

Comment: bro look at the reference image which i have already provided and i don't want do it with 100% 100% property i want to make it by cover or contain property that's the task actually.

Comment: do you know how to calculate aspect ratio area ? which is required for cover contain property

Comment: can you attach the image you want to fit and make a snippet.For aspect ratio https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp